Веб приложение на GlassFish в IntelliJ IDEA не работает
я пытаюсь запустить простое веб приложение с использованием JSF в IntelliJ IDEA и плагином GlassFish (GlassFish 7).
При запуске проблем и ошибок не возникает, однако страница index.xhtml не находится (ошибка 404), эту страницу я запускаю по пути проекта localhost:8080/testGlassFish/. При этом localhost:4848 работает нормально, я могу зайти в настройки GlassFish, однако в разделе Application моего проекта нет. Возможно я неправильно написала файл web.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <display-name>Form Based Auth Example</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>jakarta.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>jakarta.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

</web-app>

Страница index.xhtml самая обычная:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>World DB App</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>

   <p>Hello</p>
</h:body>
</html>

Файл index.xhtml лежит по пути src-main-webapp

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, что я сделала не так?
